# How to update same id in map with different field values in different field the code in not working in after update trigger on student__c object

Tags: apex, apex-trigger

There is College and Student object and college has two fields
a) Total day Scholars Students and Total Hostler Students and Students have field type (picklist-value, Hostler and Day Scholer) and update college field with total Hostler and and total Days Scholars whenever student is created, edited and deleted.

public static void afterUpdate(List<Student__c>StuList,Map<id,Student__c>StOldMap)
{
List<College__c>collList=[SELECT id,Name,Total_Day_Scholar_Students__c,Total_Hostler_Students__c FROM College__c];
list<College__c>ColUpdate=new List<College__c>();
Map<id,College__c>colMap=new Map<id,College__c>();
setcollId=new set();
for(Student__c stud:StuList)
{
if(stud.College__c!=NULL && stud.Student_Type__c!=StOldMap.get(stud.id).Student_Type__c)
{
collId.add(stud.College__c);

```
        }
        
        
    }
    //system.debug('line 18 the collId '+collId);
     List<AggregateResult>agRes=[SELECT COUNT(id)total,Student_Type__c stype,college__c clgId FROM Student__c WHERE College__c IN:collId GROUP BY Student_Type__c,college__c];
    system.debug('line 81 the aggregateRes '+agRes);
      for(AggregateResult res:agRes)
        {   String Cid=String.valueOf(res.get('clgId'));
            System.debug('line 84 the collId contains cid'+collId.contains(Cid));
         
            system.debug('the count of day schol or hostler stud is '+res.get('total'));
            String studType=String.valueOf(res.get('stype'));
            
            if(studType=='Day Scholar')
            {
                System.debug('line 88 day scholaar should be the stud type -' +studType);
                Integer dayScholar=Integer.valueOf(res.get('total'));              
                College__c collg=new College__c();
                collg.id=Cid;
                collg.Total_Day_Scholar_Students__c=dayScholar;
                //collg.Total_Hostler_Students__c=ColObj.Total_Hostler_Students__c-1;
                System.debug('the line 96 dayScholar val is'+dayScholar);
                 //System.debug('the line 97 Total_Hostler_Students__c val is'+collg.Total_Hostler_Students__c);
                ColUpdate.add(collg);
                System.debug('line 100 ColUpdate '+ColUpdate);//Id=a00GC00004jw4aaYAA, Total_Day_Scholar_Students__c=2
                
            }
            if(studType=='Hostler'){
                Integer Host=Integer.valueOf(res.get('total'));
                College__c collg=new College__c();
                collg.id=Cid;
                System.debug('the line 101 Host val is'+Host);
                collg.Total_Hostler_Students__c=Host;
            //collg.Total_Day_Scholar_Students__c=ColObj.Total_Day_Scholar_Students__c-1;
               // System.debug('the line 107 dayScholar val is'+collg.Total_Day_Scholar_Students__c);
                 System.debug('the line 108 Total_Hostler_Students__c val is'+collg.Total_Hostler_Students__c);
                ColUpdate.add(collg);
                System.debug('line 113 ColUpdate '+ColUpdate);//Id=a00GC00004jw4aaYAA, Total_Day_Scholar_Students__c=2}, 
                //College__c:{Id=a00GC00004jw4aaYAA, Total_Hostler_Students__c=1}
                
            }
        
        }
    
    //if(collId.contains(DaySchId))
    colMap.putall(ColUpdate);
    if(colMap.size()>0){
        update colMap.values();
        System.debug('line 120 colMap value '+colMap);
    }
    
}
```

}

I want below output to be stored in map.->line 113 ColUpdate '+ColUpdate);//Id=a00GC00004jw4aaYAA, Total_Day_Scholar_Students__c=2},
//College__c:{Id=a00GC00004jw4aaYAA, Total_Hostler_Students__c=1}